# law of cos in C++ visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, trigonometry

I could not figure out the inverse cosine part to make it work. Or perhaps I made more mistakes than that.

using namespace std;

```
int main()

{

    double a,b,c,angle,acos;

    cout << "Enter the value of a"<<endl;
    cin >>a;

    cout << " Enter the value of b "<<endl;
    cin >> b;

    cout << "Enter the value of c " <<endl;
    cin >> c;

    angle = acos*(-0.6481) * ((a*a+b*b-c*c)/2*a*b);

    cout << "The angle of cos is " <<angle<< endl;

    system ("pause");

}
```

Comment: No idea what you are asking but `acos` is uninitialized when you first use it.

Comment: i am trying to look for the angle.

Comment: If `acos` is initialized to 0, your angle will be 0.

Answer (score 2):

Le [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) tells us that, if a,b,c are the lengths of three sides of a triangle, the cosine of the angle of the edge facing c, is :

```
cos(angle) =  (a² + b² - c²) / 2ab    // mathematical equation, not c++ code !)
```

the inverse function fo cosinus is arccosinus, i.e. [`acos()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/acos/?kw=acos) in the c++ library.  So I guess your formula should be:

```
angle = acos((a*a+b*b-c*c)/2*a*b);
```

This result is expressed in radians.  Knowing that pi radians is 180 degrees, you can convert this to degrees:

```
#include <cmath>
...
const double pi=3.14159265;
double angle_in_deg = acos((a*a+b*b-c*c)/2*a*b) * 180/pi;
```

Please note that the syntax you have used in your original code defines `acos` to be a variable (which remains unititalized).  This is why the original formula doesn't give any correct result.